# Arrange even and odd numbers in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

given an input

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

here is my code

```
String even = "", odd = "";
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
        {
            Line[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
            if(Line[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                even = even + " " + Line[i];
            }
            else
            {
                odd = odd + " " + Line[i];
            }
        }
```

and my output

```
odd: 1 1 3 3 5 5
even: 2 2 4 4
```

i need the output to be like this

```
odd: 1 3 5
even: 2 4
```

any ideas?

Comment: Where did the 6 come from in the even output?

Comment: I would add each element to a set, sets shouldn't contain any duplicates. Then output the set to an array. I believe there is a toArray function for sets in Java

Comment: yes, we have some ideas. as your input is sorted, you could keep record of last added odd and even numbers, and do not add number if you already have one, other way will be remove duplicates from array in first place, then you dont need to worry about anything else

Comment: @user902383 i posted up new answer if you liek to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HashSet` instead of String concatenation to get only unique values.

```
Set<Integer> evenSet = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> oddSet = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
f(Line[i] % 2 == 0)
{
    evenSet.add(Line[i]); // add data to a set here instead of string concatenation
}
else
{
    oddSet.add(Line[i]);// add data to a set here instead of string concatenation
}
```

Comment: @editor(s) of this answer - I am intentionally using `LinkedHashSet` as I think it would be better to preserve ordering when compared to `HashSet`.

Comment: I posted up my answer would yuou like to see it?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing each of odd and even as a string as you iterate through the input, you should store them in a `Collection` of some kind, probably a `Set`, as that will give you the uniqueness you require for the output.

After you finish iterating, you can output the `Set` in the String format required.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with less headache and less code by using **Lambda Experssion**

Code :

```
public class LambdaTest     
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> objList = Arrays.asList(1, 1 ,2 ,2 ,3 ,3 ,4 ,4 ,5 ,5);
        System.out.print("The even numbers in the list "); 

        objList.stream().filter( i -> i %2 == 0 ).distinct().forEach(i -> System.out.print(" " + i));

        System.out.print("\n The odd numbers in the list ");

        objList.stream().filter( i -> i %2 != 0 ).distinct().forEach(i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
The even numbers in the list 2 4 
The odd numbers in the list 1 3 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This program moves the odd number to right side and all the even number to left side

package com.java.util.collection;

/**
* Arrange even and odd numbers in an Array
* @author vsinha
*
*/
public class ArrangeEvenOddInArray {


    public static void arrangeEvenOddInArray(int[] arr) {
        int i =0;
        int j =arr.length-1;
        /**
        * Moves all the odd number to right side and all the even number to left side.
        */
        while(i<j) {
            // Left side is even num and right side is odd number, no swapping
            if(isEven(arr[i]) && isOdd(arr[j])) {
                i++;
                j--;
            } else if(!isEven(arr[i]) && !isOdd(arr[j])) {// Left side is odd num and right side is even number, swapping wil come in picture
                swap(i,j,arr);
            } else if(isEven(arr[i])){
                i++;// Number is even
            } else{
                j--;// number is odd
            }

        }   
        isplay(arr);
    }


    /**
    * Display Array
    * @param arr
    */
    public static void display(int[] arr) {
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int val:arr){
            System.out.print(val +"  ");
        }
    }

    /**
    * Swapping two numbers
    * @param pos1
    * @param pos2
    * @param arr
    */
    private static void swap(int pos1, int pos2, int[] arr) {
        int temp = arr[pos1];
        arr[pos1]= arr[pos2];
        arr[pos2]= temp;
    }

    /**
    * true if number is odd
    * false if number is even
    */

    public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
        return (i & 1) != 0;
    }

    /**
    * true if number is even
    * false if number is odd
    */

    public static boolean isEven(int i) {
        return (i & 1) == 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[]={1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5};
        arrangeEvenOddInArray(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so. In addition please format your code block correctly.